# Java 11 program, GPLv2 + Classpath Exception license do I need to check everything

Tags: gpl-2, java

So following [this schema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54737381/1356107) if I wish to do everything free I can use the JDK's that are on https://jdk.java.net/

Now say that I wish to publish ready made packages for clients with jlink that I offer for download on my website. 
Following the classpath exception in the [GPLv2 + classpath exception license](https://openjdk.java.net/legal/gplv2+ce.html)

> "CLASSPATH" EXCEPTION TO THE GPL
>
> Certain source files distributed by Oracle America and/or its
>   affiliates are subject to the following clarification and special
>   exception to the GPL, but only where Oracle has expressly included in
>   the particular source file's header the words **"Oracle designates this
>   particular file as subject to the "Classpath" exception as provided by
>   Oracle in the LICENSE file that accompanied this code."**

So after compiling my program and gathering everything that has been used for distribution, do I have to check every source file of included elements from the jdk to check if that header note was put in there?

And if that sentence isn't there in one of the source files, does that mean I am forced to distribute my program/game/utility under GPLv2 or compatible?

Comment: Are you going to distribute the JDK, or just your application?

Comment: @Brandin The application will be bundled with the runtime, just like Mincraft does nowadays.

Comment: I guess it depends on which parts jlink includes. If you want a way to check, you might try removing all of the GPL (without classpath exception) sources and re-running your build to see if any part of your build fails. If the build still works after removing all GPL (without classpath exception) sources, it means your build does not depend on any GPL (without classpath exception) sources. And if it fails, it will point you to the troublemaker.